# PDO and mysql_connect at same time - performance

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a 7+ year old site which made extremely extensive use of mysql_connect/mysql_query.  I would like to begin the tedious project of converting this over to PDO, but cannot afford to take the time to go through the entire project at once.

I have done some research and searches and see that it is possible to connect to the two at the same time, however I was not able to find any information on the performance hit that this will cause.

Am I going to slow the site to a crawl while I connect with both methods?

Comment: if you have enough time, then do so

Comment: Unfortunately it will most likely be this way for a month, or possibly longer as mysql_query is called 500+ times throughout the site and I am the only one working on this project.

Comment: Well, you'll have the overhead of an additional connection that needs to be established and handled by the MySQL server. Usually this is minuscule. Whether it will have an impact on your site in particular you can only figure out by testing.

Comment: I've had to undertake such large refactoring task on a huge existing codebase, and have only one feeling about it: the sooner it is done, the better. It might take less time than you think it will, especially if you limit yourself to fixing *this particular problem* and none of the others you will probably be encountering while roaming through the code. FWIW, when doing so I did have the two connections (PDO and MySQL) at once and never noticed the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked

> Am I going to slow the site to a crawl while I connect with both methods?

No. As long

1. as your MySQL server is configured for sufficient simultaneous connections to allow two from each of your php pages, and
2. the queries you issue simultaneously from the two connections don't deadlock each other.

this should be just fine. I've done similar things with good success.

Avoiding deadlock should be easy if you're careful about overlapping queries to the same table.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't foresee any instances where I'll need to run the same query using both connections, but I can see many possible scenarios where the same table will be used.  For example one area may be writing to a table using mysql_query, while another reads using PDO (or vice versa).